# Accessing hiveconf variable in shell

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

I am wondering if it is possible to access a hiveconf variable in the shell through hive.

For instance:

`set hivevar:DIR='scripts';`

If i directly type:
   `!sh ls -l scripts`:

The output in that directory prints.

However, `!sh ls -l ${DIR}` results in

`ls: cannot access ${DIR}: No such file or directory`

I suspect this is because the variable is a hive variable and when you run the !sh command it does not recognize the `${}` syntax.  Is it possible to define a variable in an hql script, and then use it within the `!` command?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Remove single quotes from variable. Also do not write `sh` after `!`:

Let's create directory and file in it:

```
$ mkdir scripts
$ touch ./scripts/test.txt
$ ls ./scripts
test.txt
```

Now run Hive, define variable and run `ls`:

```
hive> set hivevar:DIR=scripts;
hive> ! ls ${hivevar:DIR};
test.txt
```

Let's remove directory (using `! rm -r`) in Hive and try to list it again:

```
hive> ! rm -r ${hivevar:DIR};
hive> ! ls ${hivevar:DIR};
ls: cannot access scripts: No such file or directory
Command failed with exit code = 2
```

As you can see, all works fine.

Read more about [syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveInteractiveShellCommands).

Comment: So I need to use !sh.  If i just type ! ls, I get unknown command.  I probably should have mentioned that I am using beeline.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: @tormond Yes it seems. I did not test it on beeline. But I believe it is some configuration problem in your environment, it should work without sh. Some different shell interpreter is configured by default maybe